# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion; Database Factories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, faker, factories

I have a talent model which can have many educations which I want to populate using data factories. But populating using **artisan tinker** the **education** data cause **"Array to string conversion"**.  From what I see, I am not giving an array to be converted into a string. Below are the Education's model, migration & factory

**Error Message**

`PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:/Core/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 360`

**Received On Running This Statement**

`$talents->each( function($talent) { factory(App\Education::class)->create(['talent_id' => $talent->id]); })`

```
class Education extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'talent_id',
        'institution',
        'education_level',
        'other_education_level',
        'qualification_field',
        'start_date_month',
        'start_date_year',
        'end_date_month',
        'end_date_year',
    ];

    public function talent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Talent::class);
    }
}
```

```
Schema::create('educations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('talent_id')->index();
    $table->string('institution');
    $table->string('education_level');
    $table->string('other_education_level')->nullable();
    $table->string('qualification_field');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('start_date_month');
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('start_date_year');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('end_date_month')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('end_date_year')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
$factory->define(Education::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'talent_id' => factory(\App\Talent::class),
        'institution' => $faker->word,
        'education_level' => $faker->word,
        'other_education_level' => $faker->word,
        'qualification_field' => $faker->words,
        'start_date_month' => rand(1, 12),
        'start_date_year' => rand(1970, 2000),
        'end_date_month' => rand(1, 12),
        'end_date_year' => rand(1970, 2000),
    ];
});
```

Below are the tinker commands I ran

```
$talents = App\Talent::all()
$talents->each( function($talent) { factory(App\Education::class)->create(['talent_id' => $talent->id]); })
```

The `$talents->each( function($talent) { factory(App\Education::class)->create(['talent_id' => $talent->id]); })` is the cause, but I don't understand why

The same command with different class model works say for example

```
$talents->each( function($talent) { factory(App\WorkExperience::class)->create(['talent_id' => $talent->id]); })
```

```
class WorkExperience extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'talent_id',
        'title',
        'employment_type',
        'company',
        'start_date_month',
        'start_date_year',
        'end_date_month',
        'end_date_year',
        'description',
    ];

    public function talent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Talent::class);
    }
}
```

```
Schema::create('work_experiences', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('talent_id')->index();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('employment_type');
    $table->string('company');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('start_date_month');
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('start_date_year');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('end_date_month')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('end_date_year')->nullable();
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
$factory->define(WorkExperience::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'talent_id' => factory(\App\Talent::class),
        'title' => $faker->word,
        'employment_type' => $faker->word(['Internship', 'Part Time', 'Full Time']),
        'company' => $faker->word,
        'start_date_month' => rand(1, 12),
        'start_date_year' => rand(1970, 2000),
        'end_date_month' => rand(1, 12),
        'end_date_year' => rand(1970, 2000),
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
```

Comment: please add the full error message too

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was initially posted from the [Laracasts website](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-notice-array-to-string-conversion-database-factories) forum and I've just received the solution.

The issue was in my EducationFactory:

```
'qualification_field' => $faker->words
```

$faker->words return an array of strings. The solution is to use **$faker->sentence**

```
'qualification_field' => $faker->sentence
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue probably lies in this piece of code:

```
'talent_id' => factory(\App\Talent::class),
```

The factory method will return an array of data for the Talent class, and will try to apply it to the `talent_id` , and fail.

To correct your problem, do:

```
'talent_id' => function () { return factory(\App\Talent::class)->create()->id; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that was not the issues. If that were to run, I bet it would create new talents instead of resuing the existing ones

Comment: Yes, it would create new Talents, that's the point of using nested factories. But I'm glad you found your answer. I didn't pick up on the Faker calls.